# configuring Munin for Nginx 1.2.4 on ubuntu 10.04 ubuntu ec2 instances

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04, ruby, munin

I am running my ruby on rails app ubuntu 10.04 ec2 instance and I am using nginx 1.2.4. I am trying to configure munin to get stats fron nginx, I have recompiled nginx and its working fine but I am unable to run the munin. If I hit mydomain.com/munin/ I am getting error 404 page not found. Also I have installed all the necessary plugins for the munin like nginx-stats,nginx-memory and many more. Googling did not sole my issue, because people are suggesting to add configuration setting to sites-available/defaults, but my Nginx doesnt have any such kind of folder. Kindly help me

Comment: You want to generate the statistics locally on the machine? Did you installed munin and munin-node packages? Do you really need munin or just some nice stats?

Comment: @cstamas I have already installed munin,munin-node, but whenever I hit IP/munin/ I get 404 error. also I need stats from the production.It would be good get nice stats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an location alias to your munin installation. There is no automatic link between your webserver and the Munin document directory.

Try to add something like this to the nginx virtualhost you want to access `/munin/` on.

```
location /munin/ {
  alias /var/cache/munin/www/;
}
```

This path, `/var/cache/munin/www/` is the default munin web-path on Ubuntu 12.04 and it might be a different path on your system.